# Unexpected line break in views on Favorites Tab of User Page

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface, si-prefix

On the Questions and Favorites tab of an individual's User page, the number of views for a question is presented as an integer. When that integer exceeds 1000, it's listed as the number of thousands (e.g., "3k views"). For some reason, the linebreak occurs between the number and the 'k' instead of the 'k' and "views".

In other words, 13000-odd views appears like this:

```
13
kviews
```

...instead of like this:

```
13k
views
```

Obviously, this is a low-priority aesthetic correction, but it exists nonetheless. I've observed this on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer on my Windows 7 64bit system.